# Need Help to fix the css or style sheet on website home page

Tags: css, border, stylesheet, box, osclass

On my website [enter link description here](http://7Emirate.com)

Home page last row of latest ads showing on home page is not coming in line can anyone one help me with css or any other way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to you not having the salary on each advertisement.

If you add `<h4 class="colorfull">1.00 Dirham د.إ</h4>`from 'Primavera P6' onto the next one 'Required female real estate agent' you'll notice the layout rearranges itself.

You have to ensure standardization between advertisement images/structure, or by defining strict sizes within the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The heights of the ads don't correspond. Add the below code to give them all the same height. And i noticed the images weren't centered.

```
.caption {
            min-height: 130px;
        }

    /**Add the below to center image **/
        .thumbnaile > .lefter {
         text-align: center;
        }
```

Comment: Blecaf how to add this and where to add this can you please tell little more becuase i dont know programming :-)

Comment: You need to add this in your style.css file. Are you using Wordpress?

Comment: No i am using osclass